# Hibernate returns the list of null

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to use Hibernate but when I execute a query I receive a list of my entity where all the attributes are NULL. The thing is that when i use the jdbc directly I am able to retrieve the values from my Db.
I read similar articles about NULL values but couldn't figure out what s wrong in my case. 
Below you see:
1) My entity: Eshop

```
public class Eshop  implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Eshop() {}

    public Eshop(int eshopId, String code, String name, String lastModified) {
    this.eshopId = eshopId;
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}

    public int eshopId;

    public String code;

    public String name;

    public String lastModified;

    public int getEshopId() {
        return eshopId;
    }

    public void setEshopId(int eshopId) {
        eshopId = eshopId;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        code = code;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }


    public String getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(String lastModified) {
        lastModified = lastModified;
    }
```

2) The Hibernate Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="dataModel.Eshop" table="Eshop">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the Eshop details. 
      </meta>
      <id name="eshopId" type="int" column="EshopId">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="code" column="Code" type="string"/>
      <property name="name" column="Name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastModified" column="LastModified" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is how I run the query:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(); 
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Query hibernateQuery = session.createQuery("from Eshop");
List<Eshop> Eshops = hibernateQuery.list();
```

So when I run a query i receive the exact number of Eshops which are in my Db but all their attributes values are null!!
An ideas?? Thank you

Comment: you are referencing a local variable scope to the same local variable scope.

Comment: right, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your setters are wrong:

```
public void setEshopId(int eshopId) {
    eshopId = eshopId;
}
```

This is a noop. It should be

```
public void setEshopId(int eshopId) {
    this.eshopId = eshopId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `hibernate.cfg.xml` like this:

```
   Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```